# Queuing js functions

Tags: javascript

Sorry, if this question was asked before - i haven't found the answer for my case.

I have one function, which will be called again and again asynchronously.
I need to avoid concurrent execution of this function.

Here the example:

```
const q = // some kind of queue;

let v = 0;
const fun = (arg) => {
    console.log('v', v)
    setTimeout(() => {
        v = v + arg;
        // return true;
        q.next()
    }, 1000)
}


q.add(fun(2))
q.add(fun(3))
q.add(fun(4))
q.add(fun(5))
```

This is the logs i want to see at the end:

```
v 0
v 2
v 5
v 9
v 14
```

Comment: Take a look at the async library. It does this for you https://github.com/caolan/async Particularly the "series(...)" function

Comment: `fun()` doesn't return anything, what are you expecting to put in the queue?

Comment: @Barmar i intend to put there quite complicated functions with async rest calls. I need to have way to say "this function finished, check if there is next one" in each of queued functions

Comment: Is the argument to `q.add()` supposed to be a function to call? You're not passing a function, you're calling the function and passing its value to `q.add()`.

Comment: and i need to be able to add any quantity of new functions in the queue any time (there might be no functions for minutes and there might be dozen functions added within a second_

Comment: @Barmar, `q.add()` is just attempt to explain what i mean: add one more function into queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use an array.

Note that my code's output is slightly different from yours—I don't get "v 14". I'm not sure why you expect that output... you're queueing up four function calls but expect five lines of output?

```
const q = [];

let v = 0;
function fun (arg) {
  console.log('v', v);
  setTimeout(() => {
    v = v + arg;
    var next = q.shift();
    if (next) { next(); }
  });
}

q.push(() => { fun(2); });
q.push(() => { fun(3); });
q.push(() => { fun(4); });
q.push(() => { fun(5); });

q.shift()(); // run the first one

// OUTPUT:
// v 0
// v 2
// v 5
// v 9
```

**EDIT**

Here's perhaps a better version that has the added advantage that it will work properly no matter when things are enqueued. In the above code, you have to manually start running things, and once the queue is exhausted, nothing later added will ever be run. In the below `FunctionQueue` class, execution happens automatically whenever there's at least one function to run:

```
class FunctionQueue {
  constructor() {
    this.queue = [];
    this.running = false;
  }

  go() {
    if (this.queue.length) {
      this.running = true;
      this.queue.shift()(() => { this.go(); });
    } else {
      this.running = false;
    }
  }

  add(func) {
    this.queue.push(func);

    if(!this.running) {
      this.go();
    }
  }
}

let v = 0;
function fun (arg, cb) {
  console.log('v', v);
  v += arg;
  setTimeout(cb, 100);
}

const q = new FunctionQueue();
// Execution will automatically start once something is enqueued.
q.add((cb) => { fun(2, cb); });
q.add((cb) => { fun(3, cb); });
q.add((cb) => { fun(4, cb); });
q.add((cb) => { fun(5, cb); });

// At this point, nothing's running anymore.

// Enqueueing something much later will resume execution again.
setTimeout(() => {
  q.add((cb) => { fun(6, cb); });
}, 1000);

// OUTPUT:
// v 0
// v 2
// v 5
// v 9
// v 15
```

Comment: how do i add new one in 10 minutes or so after initial execution?

Comment: @stkvtflw See my edit, which should handle that case nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Promise`. Any resolution of first one, call the second one and so on..

```
let v = 0;
const fun = (arg) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('v', v)
        v = v + arg;
        resolve(true);
    }, 1000)
  });
}

var promise = func(0);
for (var i =1; i< 10; i++){
  (function(n){
    promise = promise.then(()=>{
       return func(n);
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: how do i add new one in 10 minutes or so after initial execution?

Answer (score 0):

This will be started with `fun()` and **continue to run while there are increment definitions left** in the queue:

```js
const queue = [];

const fun = (start) => {
    start = start || 0
    console.log('v', start)
    setTimeout(() => {
        if(queue.length > 0) {
          const increment = queue.shift();
          fun(start + increment);
        }
    }, 1000)
}

queue.push(2)
queue.push(3)
fun()
queue.push(4)
queue.push(5)
```

Note that depending on your browser, **the `const` keyword may not be supported** and needs to be transpiled to ES5 or replaced with the `var` keyword.